# Firebase functions: sequence of calls

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase proceed async calls in series or not?

I have two calls as mentioned below. Is it possible that 2nd call going to finish early than 1st one?

```
var p1 = admin.database().ref(path1).set(value1);
var p2 = admin.database().ref(path2).set(value2);

return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Realtime Database, no, it is not possible for the case you've shown. The operations will complete in the order they were executed.

Comment: Is it actual for sequence of calls from Android SDK too?

Comment: It's true for all platforms.  The behavior is driven by the server, no the client.